# No route matches [PATCH] "/admin/roles.4"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I made model Role with rolify gem.
But controller made to namespace :admin :

```
class Admin::RolesController < ApplicationController

def index
    @roles = Role.all
end
def new
    @role = Role.new
end

def create
    @role = Role.new(role_params)
    respond_to do |format|
        if @role.save
            format.html { redirect_to admin_role_path(@role), notice: 'Роль создана.' }
            format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @role }
        else
            format.html { render action: 'new' }
            format.json { render json: @role.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
    end
end

def show
    @role = Role.find(params[:id])
end

def edit
    @role = Role.find(params[:id])
end

def update
    respond_to do |format|
        if @role.update(role_params)
            format.html { redirect_to admin_role_path(@role), notice: 'Роль обновлена.' }
            format.json { head :no_content }
        else
            format.html { render action: 'edit' }
            format.json { render json: @role.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
    end
end

def destroy
    @role = Role.find(params[:id])
    @role.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to admin_roles_url }
        format.json { head :no_content }
    end
end

private
    def set_role
        @role = Role.find(params[:id])
    end

    def role_params
        params.require(:role).permit(:name)
    end
end
```

When I want to update Role, I open form, edit, click submit and get error:

```
Routing Error
No route matches [PATCH] "/admin/roles.4"
```

Please help me.

Comment: Can you show your routes.rb ?

Comment: Form:  = simple_form_for @role, url: admin_roles_path(@role), :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f|
  = f.error_notification

  .form-inputs
    = f.input :name, input_html: { class: 'input-xlarge' }

  .form-actions
    = f.button :submit, :value => 'Сохранить', :class => 'btn btn-primary'

Comment: routes.rb:    Freshapp::Application.routes.draw do
  namespace :admin do
    resources :deliveries
    resources :roles
    root 'dashboard#index'
  end

  devise_for :users

  root 'home#index'

end

Comment: can you include your output of rake routes, please. (and please: edit your question and do not put the output in a comment.)

Answer (score 2):

Based on the form code you pasted above, you'll see that `url` is pointing to the path used for creates but not updates.

You should be able to update your call to `simple_form` like so:

```
= simple_form_for [:admin, @role], :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f|
```

You'll see that you can pass an array with symbolized namespace names and the object instance, and it'll build the URL correctly for both `POST`s and `PATCH`es.

Comment: No, this is my route.rb:  

`Freshapp::Application.routes.draw do  
  namespace :admin do  
    resources :deliveries  
    resources :roles  
    root 'dashboard#index'  
  end  
  devise_for :users  
  root 'home#index'  
end`

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved.

In _form I fix url.

```
= simple_form_for @role, url: admin_role_path(@role), :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f|
```